# Data doesn't bring forward to 1st page using ng-if

Tags: angularjs

I have problem displaying data on ng-repeat, lets say I have this set of sample data

```
$scope.sample={"a","b","c","d","e","f","test"}
```

i'll show data if sample includes 'test',

```
<tr ng-repeat="data in sample track by $index" ng-if="data.includes('test')">
```

my table will show 4 data in each page

```
$scope.table = new ngTableParams({
                    page: 1,
                    count: 4    })
```

However, when you run the code, the 1st page is blank, I need to navigate to the 2nd page to see the data 'test' as it's on the 7th position.

My question is, is there a solution to bring visible field forward? and since only 1 data is visible in the table, it should only have 1 page instead of 2 page.

Thanks

Comment: Am I correct to assume you're using **ng-table**? (http://ng-table.com/#/filtering/demo-filtering-basic). If that's the case why don't you use the built in filters? `ng-if` will interfiere with the inner workings of **ng-table**.

Comment: I'm using server side filtering. I'm currently trying to hide url with querystring